# Is there any way to remove windowClass from $uibModal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-modal

My modal popup is open and windowClass is added successfully according to the condition. But I need to toggle windowClass in some conditions. Is there any way to toggle windowClass while modal is open.

Here is the code...

```
  // AddClass conatin a boolean value
  $scope.openModal = function (addClass) {
      $uibModal.open({
         templateUrl: 'app/Views/modalView.html',
         controller: 'modalController',
         windowClass: addClass ? 'app-modal-window' : ''
      });
  }

  $scope.openModal(true); // Call function to open modal popup
```

Comment: Does your code not work?

Comment: No, my code is working fine. I need to toggle windowClass on some conditions.

Comment: Is `addClass` not the condition? Your question is very unclear

Comment: yes, addClass is a condition and assume it contain a boolean value true.

Comment: So what’s the problem? Is app-modal-class always present or something?

Comment: I need to remove app-modal-class on behalf of some condition.

Comment: Yes, what is the code currently doing? Could you post a fiddle maybe?

Comment: @all this issue is resolved.